# How can I upgrade lubuntu 14.04 to 15.04?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

Will I lose my configurations or it's simple to do?

Comment: You'll need to go 14.04->14.10->15.04, and I am not sure why you'd do it. Note that 14.10 is no longer supported, so that you'll need to manually edit the sources list.

Comment: Recommendation : Install 15.04 from scratch or wait a few weeks and install 15.10. - As you have a LTS version installed you should consider to replace it with the next one, which is 16.04 !

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to go 14.04->14.10->15.04, and I am not sure why you'd do it. Note that 14.10 is no longer supported, so that you'll need to manually edit the sources list. Unless there are very good reasons to upgrade, I'd suggest staying with 14.04, and upgrading to 16.04 in due course.